# PHP Drop Down Boxes always Isset

Tags: php, isset

HI i have two drop down boxes which are used to filter data from a mysql table, the problem is the boxes always show as if they are set when i use isset to determin if any of them have any values selected.

Here is the code for the drop boxes.

```
 <?php 
                       if (isset($_POST['referrer']) && $_POST['referrer'] != "referrer") {
                       $select = $_POST['referrer'];
                         }
                       ?>
                                    <select name="referrer">
                                    <option value="">Referrer</option>

                                      <?php
                       // Get records from database (table "name_list").
                       $list=mysql_query("select DISTINCT referrer from masterip_details WHERE country_code='GB' AND TRIM(IFNULL(referrer,'')) <> '' order by referrer DESC");
                       // Show records by while loop.
                       while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
                       $referrer = $_POST['referrer']; ?>
                                      <option value="<?php echo $row_list['referrer']; ?>" <?php if($row_list['referrer']==$select){ echo "selected"; } ?>><?php echo $row_list['referrer']; ?></option>        
                                      <?php     
                       }
                       ?>
                                    </select>



 <?php 
                       if (isset($_POST['returning']) && $_POST['returning'] != "returning") {
                       $select2 = $_POST['returning'];
                         }
                       ?>
                                    <select name="returning">
                                    <option value="">Referrer</option>
                                      <?php
                       // Get records from database (table "name_list").
                       $list2=mysql_query("select * from repeater_drop_down order by id DESC");
                       // Show records by while loop.
                       while($row_list2=mysql_fetch_assoc($list2)){
                       $returning = $_POST['returning']; ?>
                                      <option value="<?php echo $row_list2['value']; ?>" <?php if($row_list2['value']==$select2){ echo "selected"; } ?>><?php echo $row_list2['title']; ?></option>     
                                      <?php     
                       }
                       ?>
                                    </select>
```

Now here are the isset elements of the code.

```
$returning = $_POST['returning'];
$referrer = $_POST['referrer'];

 if (isset($returning, $referrer)){

 //code //

  elseif (isset($returning)){

   ///code //

  elseif (isset($referrer)){

  //code //

  else {

 //code   

        }
```

I haven't included the queries as they work fine but whether or not i select both drop down boxes the code automatically goes to the first isset for both variable even if only one of the boxes has a option selected.

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: They both always have an option selected.  So that first condition will always be true.  The value for that option may be an empty string, but it's still a value.

Comment: Have you tried changing `isset` to `empty` to see if you get better results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the value that was submitted with the form, not only whether or not the select POST value is set.

The value of the referrer will be `''` (an empty string) if it is submitted without changing the select. Check for that instead.